# model does not exit in your database (prisma ) and Error: P1001

Tags: mysql, docker, prisma

After I create a docker-compose.yml like this:

```yaml
services:
  server: 
    build: .
    ports: 
      - "3000:3000"
    environment:
      - DATABASE_URL=mysql://root:root@mysqldb:3306/mydb?schema=public
    links: 
     - mysqldb
    depends_on:
      - mysqldb
  mysqldb:
    image: mysql
    ports: 
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=mydb
```

and a Dockerfile :

```bash
FROM node:18
RUN mkdir -p /home/app
COPY . /home/app
WORKDIR /home/app
EXPOSE 3000
RUN npm install
CMD ["sh", "-c", "npx prisma migrate dev --name init && node src/index.js"]
```

I got the following error in my terminal when I ran docker compose up:

```
 Datasource "db": MySQL database "mydb" at "mysqldb:3306
server-1   | Error: P1001: Can't reach database server at mysqldb: 3306
server-1   | Please make sure your database server is running at mysqldb:3306
```

or also :  `Model Does not exit in your database`

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION: I solve this problem by using command sleep, docker compose build simultaneously both apps, so if db is not ready to receive connections prisma could not make your db models, so adding sleep 20 i solve this in the CMD dockerfile:

```bash
FROM node:18
RUN mkdir -p /home/app
COPY . /home/app
WORKDIR /home/app
EXPOSE 3000
RUN npm install
CMD ["sh", "-c", "sleep 20 npx prisma migrate dev --name init && node src/index.js"]
```

then Run docker compose build to make sure your docker compose up command detect changes in your dockerfile
`

Comment: If this is your problem, the more general approaches in [Docker Compose wait for container X before starting Y](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31746182/docker-compose-wait-for-container-x-before-starting-y) might be more robust.